# Why is the React useEffect hook not activating when a component is reloaded after previously throwing an error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am learning React and Redux within a Typescript environment. I have managed to implement a container that dispatches a fetch action and subscribes to corresponding fetch success and error state notifications from a redux store. The source code is listed below:

**Container**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { GridSpacing } from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

import Course from '../components/Course/Course';

import { courseModels } from '../redux/features/course';
import { courseSelectors } from '../redux/features/course';
import { fetchCoursesAsync } from '../redux/features/course/actions';

import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { RootState } from 'ReduxTypes';

import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router';

type ErrorReport = { hasError: boolean; error?: Error };
type StateProps = {
  isLoading: boolean;
  courses: courseModels.Course[];
  error: ErrorReport;
};

/**
 * Redux dispatch and state mappings
 */
const dispatchProps = {
  fetchCourses: fetchCoursesAsync.request,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState): StateProps => ({
  isLoading: state.courses.isLoadingCourses,
  courses: courseSelectors.getReduxCourses(state.courses),
  error: courseSelectors.getReduxCoursesError(state.courses),
});

/**
 * Component property type definitions
 */
type Props = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> &
  typeof dispatchProps &
  RouteComponentProps;

/**
 * CourseList component
 */
const CourseList = ({
  courses = [],
  error,
  fetchCourses,
  history,
  isLoading,
}: Props): JSX.Element => {
  // fetch course action on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('COURSELIST FETCHING COURSES');
    fetchCourses();
  }, [fetchCourses]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  if (error && error.hasError && error.error) {
    console.log('COURSELIST ENCOUNTERED AN ERROR');
    // option 1. history.push('/error'); // triggers state transition error
    // option 2. throw error.error;
    // if throw the error from state then encapsulating error boundary catches and displays
    // however subsequent request actions are not processed by redux-observable action stream
    // needs further investigation and if necessary a subsequent question posted....
    // if render error inside component then redux-observable stream continues
    // to process subsequent actions.
    return <Redirect to="/error" />;
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: 20, padding: 30 }}>
      {
        <Grid container spacing={2 as GridSpacing} justify="center">
          {courses.map(element => (
            <Grid item key={element.courseID}>
              <Course course={element} />
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      }
    </div>
  );
};

/**
 * Exports
 */
export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    dispatchProps,
  )(CourseList),
);
```

If I throw an error within the container then the encapsulating error boundary catches and displays it. However, when the container is reloaded via clicking on a Navbar link the useEffect
action does not trigger. Subsequently, the fetchCourses action is not dispatched.

Why is the *useEffect* hook not triggered on second load after it previously threw an error?

Have tried suggestion in comments to redirect to an error page instead of throwing the error. This resulted in the error displayed in the image below:

[image: Error screenshot when redirect to /error page]

The *useEffect* seems to be triggered with this approach, each time the page is visited. However, I think that what is happening is that there is a race condition occurring between *useEffects* and the render on each subsequent visit to the page. The inspection of the error state and redirection to /error seems to be happening while a fetch is in progress..... Maybe resort to using a class component, unless there is a way to wait for *useEffects* to complete before rendering?

Another suggestion is to use  tag instead of `history.push(url)`. This was successful in the sense that no error was displayed in console related to transitive state. Nearly there now....experiencing the following behaviour:

1. Stop external API server
2. Visit the container page (CourseList). On load it makes the request via dispatching fetch action onto redux store.
3. Fetch Error state is then detected on redux store and redirected to error page.
4. Start external API server again
5. Visit the container page (CourseList) page again. Redirected to error page.
6. Revisit the container page (CourseList) page again. CourseList displayed.

**Error Boundary Component**

```js
import React, { Component, ErrorInfo, ReactNode } from 'react';

import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

import * as stackTrace from 'stacktrace-js';
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { UnregisterCallback } from 'history';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

type ErrorBoundaryProps = {};
type ErrorBoundaryState = {
  hasError: boolean;
  error?: Error;
  info?: ErrorInfo;
};

class ErrorBoundary extends Component<
  ErrorBoundaryProps & RouteComponentProps,
  ErrorBoundaryState
> {
  private static homePath = '/';

  private unlisten!: UnregisterCallback;

  constructor(props: ErrorBoundaryProps & RouteComponentProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hasError: false,
      error: undefined,
      info: undefined,
    };
    this.goHome = this.goHome.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(): void {
    this.unlisten = this.props.history.listen(() => {
      if (this.state.hasError) {
        this.setState({ hasError: false });
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount(): void {
    this.unlisten();
  }

  async componentDidCatch(error: Error, info: ErrorInfo): Promise<void> {
    console.log(`Error => ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
    console.log(`ErrorInfo => ${JSON.stringify(info)}`);
    this.setState({
      hasError: true,
      error: APP_CONF.isProd ? await this.normaliseError(error) : error,
      info: info,
    });
  }

  goHome(): void {
    this.props.history.push(ErrorBoundary.homePath);
  }

  render(): JSX.Element | ReactNode {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return (
        <p>Error</p>
        // <Dialog
        //   open={this.state.hasError}
        //   onClose={this.goHome}
        //   aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        //   aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        //   scroll="paper"
        // >
        //   <DialogTitle
        //     disableTypography
        //     id="alert-dialog-title"
        //     style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightseagreen', color: 'cyan' }}
        //   >
        //     <Typography variant="h6">
        //       {this.state.error
        //         ? this.state.error.message
        //         : 'error message unavailable'}
        //     </Typography>
        //   </DialogTitle>
        //   <DialogContent>
        //     <DialogContentText component="div" id="alert-dialog-description">
        //       <Typography
        //         variant="caption"
        //         style={{ color: 'midnightblue' }}
        //         component="span"
        //       >
        //         <Box textAlign="justify" mt={1} style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre' }}>
        //           {this.state.error
        //             ? this.state.error.stack
        //             : 'stack trace unavailable'}
        //         </Box>
        //         <Box textAlign="justify" mt={1} style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre' }}>
        //           {this.state.info && APP_CONF.mode !== 'production'
        //             ? this.state.info.componentStack
        //             : 'component stack unavailable in production'}
        //           <br />
        //         </Box>
        //       </Typography>
        //     </DialogContentText>
        //   </DialogContent>
        //   <DialogActions>
        //     <Button onClick={this.goHome}>Home</Button>
        //   </DialogActions>
        // </Dialog>
      );
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }

  private async normaliseError(error: Error): Promise<Error> {
    const stackFrames: Array<
      stackTrace.StackFrame
    > = await stackTrace.fromError(error);

    const stack: string = stackFrames.reduce((prev, cur) => {
      return prev.toString() + cur.toString() + '\n';
    }, '');

    return {
      name: error.name,
      message: error.message,
      stack: stack.trim(),
    };
  }
}

export default withRouter(ErrorBoundary);
```

**Routing**

```js
import React, { Component, Suspense, lazy } from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import ErrorBoundary from '../errors/ErrorBoundary';
import { NavBar } from './NavBar/NavBar';

/**
 * Lazy load definitions
 */
const About = lazy(() =>
  import(
    /*
  webpackChunkName: "about-page",
  webpackPrefetch: true
  */ '../views/About/About'
  ),
);

const CourseList = lazy(() =>
  import(
    /*
  webpackChunkName: "course-list",
  webpackPrefetch: true
  */ '../containers/CourseList'
  ),
);

const Home = lazy(() =>
  import(
    /*
webpackChunkName: "home-page",
webpackPrefetch: true
*/ '../views/Home/Home'
  ),
);

type AppProps = {};

export class App extends Component<AppProps, {}> {
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <NavBar />
          <Suspense fallback={<div>LoaderOptionsPlugin...</div>}>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" component={Home} exact></Route>
              <Route path="/about" component={About}></Route>
              <Route
                path="/courses"
                render={(props): JSX.Element => (
                  <ErrorBoundary {...props}>
                    <CourseList />
                  </ErrorBoundary>
                )}
              ></Route>
              {/* <Route component={Error404}></Route> */}
            </Switch>
          </Suspense>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Upon error thrown at `render` stage your component still is instantiated. So it will not be recreated, neither `props.fetchCourses` is changed. So React does not see any need to re-run `useEffect`. Hard to propose elegant solution by now, you use routing, right? Probably, redirecting to some different component in case of error("/error") would be easiest way. Then navigating back to "/" would re-create your component and re-run `fetch()` in `useEffect`

Comment: Thanks @skyboyer, much appreciated :) Yep, using routing. I have since added a home button to my ErrorBoundary component for redirecting to '/'. However, after clicking home, if I then click on link to display my CourseList container the ErrorBoundary is again displayed. I do not see console log message in useEffect. When navigating back to '/courses' should this recreate the _CourseList_ container? Is this not happening because the error was thrown in render previously, so container is reused? Amending question to include routing class and will investigate your redirect approach....

Comment: Hi @skyboyer, just tried routing to /error @skyboyer and have updated question with details. Get an error in console, that ```Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state. ``` On subsequent visits back to the container there seems to be a race condition between the fetch completing in useEffects and the redirection based on check of error state....Wonder if there is someway to wait until useEffects has completed?

Comment: Instead of pushing to history try rendering a `<Redirect to="/error" />` component. Using `history.push()` (state update) in a render method (your functional component) will result in that error.

Comment: Many thanks @Grabofus. Yep, that gets rid of the error concerning cannot update an existing state transition... :) Almost there...if I stop the external API server, causing a network connection error in client, then redirected to error page ok. If I then restart the external API server and revisit the link then the error is still displayed. If I then visit the link again the course list is displayed

Comment: When you revisit the link, you mean revisit `/error` page of your site? It seems correct to me that the error message is still there.

Comment: If I revisit ```/courses``` link after restarting API server, it redirects to error page. If I revisit ```/courses``` link again it displays the list of courses. Sequence of events that occur are:
1. Stop external API server
2. Visit the container page (CourseList). It makes request via dispatching fetch action onto redux store.
3. Fetch Error state is detected from store and redirected to error page.
4. Start external API server again
5. Revisit the container page (CourseList) again. Redirected to error page.
6. Revisit the container page (CourseList) page again. CourseList displayed.

Comment: Apologies @Grabofus for list formatting in my response comment. Have amended question with clearer formatted list